# Making a Web Chat with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, chat

I am trying to implement a browser based chat system with jQuery. I want to poll the server for new messages and append them to the bottom of a div. I have two problems.

- I can't get it to append text to the div
- I don't know how to keep the div scrolled to the bottom as the text gets appended

Here's the relevant clip of my HTML:

```
<div id="main">
 <form action='post.php' method='post'>
  <div id='messages'>stuff</div><br />
  <input type='text' name='usertext' />
 </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're missing here.

```
$(selector).append('<div class="message">sometext</div>');
```

And how to [scroll to the bottom of a div](http://radio.javaranch.com/pascarello/2005/12/14/1134573598403.html)

Comment: Based solely on your provided code, Ben's example would expand to $('div#main div#messages').append('<div class="message">sometext</div>');

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to scrollto automatically:

```
var oldscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
//chatbox is the id of div
var newscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
if(newscrollHeight > oldscrollHeight)
{
    $("#chatbox").animate({ scrollTop: newscrollHeight }, 'normal');
}
```